# How to use an initialization list with std::thread as a member in C++11

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio-2012, c++11, initialization, stdthread

I am trying to create a vector with a class as its template which has a *std::thread* member. However, I am not sure on how to properly create the initialization list using the thread. What I have currently is this:

```
class someclass 
{
public:
std::thread thread;
int id;

someclass(std::thread init_thread, int init_id) : 
    thread(&init_thread), 
    id(init_id)
{}
};
```

However, when I try to compile it in VS2012, I get the following error:

f:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\functional(1152): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments
which point to the line:
_VARIADIC_EXPAND_0X(_CLASS_BIND, , , , )

If I remove the & from the thread(&init_thread) initialization I get those errors instead:
1>f:\users...\project\source.cpp(43): error C2248: 'std::thread::thread' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::thread'
1>          f:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\thread(73) : see declaration of 'std::thread::thread'
1>          f:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\thread(32) : see declaration of 'std::thread'

So, my question is: How would I correctly created such an initialization list?

Later on in the code I doing the following as well (just for reference...)

```
void function()
{
   // ....
   std::vector<someclass> v_someclass;
   v_someclass.push_back(someclass((std::thread(session, socket)),id));   
   // ....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code. The most important one is that `std::thread` is not copy-constructable, but only *move-copy constructable*. You can make this intent clear by having an rvalue reference as parameter, and you have to use `std::move` when constructing the thread data member. Second, you should not take the address of the parameter. Your data member is not a pointer.

```
someclass(std::thread&& init_thread, int init_id) : 
  thread(std::move(init_thread)), 
  id(init_id)
```

This means you can only construct `someclass` using an `std::thread` *rvalue*. For example

```
someclass sc0(std::thread(args), 42);
std::thread t(args);
someclass sc1(std::move(t), 42);
```

**Edit** Note that you *can* actually have a value parameter: `someclass(std::thread, int)`, but the error message you get when passing an lvalue is not as clear as the one you get with the rvalue reference parameter.

Comment: You do not **need** sn rvalue ref as a parameter.  A value works fine.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! That answer is exactly what I was looking for and couldn't get a clear understanding anywhere else on the net.

Comment: @juanchopanza I guess another follow up question regarding the construct. If I wanted to construct the object anonymously using it in the push_back of the vector, how come I could not just do it like
`v_someclass.push_back(someclass((std::thread(session, socket)),id));`
Would that not be the same as defining them seperate as in 
`someclass sc0(std::thread(session, socket),42);
v_someclass.push_back(sc0);`
?

Comment: @Yakk Yes, correct. But I prefer to make the intent clearer, and also benefit from a clearer error message in the case when an lvalue is passed. I added a sentence about that.